# Simply inserting to temp table and failing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, temporary-tables

Can anyone tell me why this won't work for me?

```
CREATE TABLE #UndistributedCmds
(
pendingcmdcount int,
estimatedprocesstime INT
)
INSERT INTO #UndistributedCmds

EXEC sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds ...
```

The error:

> Msg 8164, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds, Line 152
> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

The error seems to imply that line 152 of the stored procedure definition is the issue, but I'm having trouble understanding this. Is this happening because the stored procedure itself has multiple stored procedures within it?

Comment: where you inserted into `#UndistributedCmds` table

Comment: More accurately, the `dbo.sp_replmonitorsubscriptionpendingcmds` procedure cannot be calling a procedure ( or one that calls a procedure, etc. ) which does an `INSERT EXEC` as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error is happening because the stored procedure also has a #temp table or table variable and inserts into it using `insert...exec`. You can see it by looking at its `OBJECT_DEFINITION()`:

```
insert into @countab (pendingcmdcount)  
  exec @retcode = sys.sp_MSget_repl_commands
```

So basically you asking for this (pseudo-code):

```
INSERT INTO #outer EXEC
  (SELECT * FROM (INSERT INTO #inner EXEC ... ));
```

This nesting of `insert...exec` calls is prohibited in SQL Server, for reasons that are unknown/undocumented. The typical workaround is:

```
SELECT * INTO #UndistributedCmds
  FROM OPENQUERY([LoopbackLinkedServer], N'EXEC procedure...');
```

You'll need a linked server that references the local server machine, and it will need the attribute "data access" set to true...